# In angular route provider setting page title based on url

Tags: angularjs, routes

How do I access the url in the `setTitle` anonymous function?

I have something like below in my route setup for Angular.  Most routes point to the same controller, there are some differences in the controller but essentially the problem is duplicated routes.  So I want to move to something that only has one entry in the table, but need to change the SetWindowTitle to set the title based on the url paramter.  The code I have displayed does not work as the `producttype` var is undefined.

Current code:

```
.config(['$routeProvider',
    function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/mypage/round', {
            templateUrl: 'product',
            controller: 'productController',
            resolve: {
                setTitle: function() { 
                    SetWindowTitle('product round')
                }
            },
        })
        .when('/mypage/square', {
            templateUrl: 'product',
            controller: 'productController',
            resolve: {
                setTitle: function() { 
                    SetWindowTitle('product square')
                }
            },
        })
   // etc...
```

Want something like:

```
    $routeProvider
        .when('/mypage/:producttype', {
            templateUrl: 'product',
            controller: 'productController',
            resolve: {
                setTitle: function() { 
                    SetWindowTitle('product ' + producttype)
                }
            },
        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can access the route URL in the resolve function by injecting '$route'.
Here is what you need to do :

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/mypage/:producttype', {
        templateUrl: 'product',
        controller: 'productController',
        resolve: {
            setTitle: function($route) { 
                SetWindowTitle('product ' + $route.current.params.producttype)
            }
        },
    })
```

> $route.current - Consist of all the current route URL details, like the controller, original path, path, template url etc.

Comment: Thanks - works great, note that it broke because of the minification when I tried it. Hope you dont mind, I updated your answer to cover that.

Comment: your welcome, yeah you need to put it in array which should be the practice actually but had to just give you the answer by changing your code snippet, so skipped it.